# symfony 3 swiftmalier don't deliver mails

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer, yahoo, smtpclient

I have some issue with swiftmailer on symfony 3 i spend 3 days searching the problem without any result
I want to send confirmation mail for my web application, the function of sending mails run correctly but the request retun with statut 302 and log error :
Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Expected response code 220 but got code "", with message "" so the mail is not dilivered

and here is my confugration files

config.yml

```
swiftmailer:
transport: '%mailer_transport%'
host: '%mailer_host%'
encryption: ssl
port: 465
username: '%mailer_user%'
password: '%mailer_password%'
spool: {type: memory}
```

parameters.yml

```
parameters:
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: smtp.mail.yahoo.com
mailer_user: test@yahoo.com
mailer_password: test
secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
```

and the maillin action

```
public function mailingAction()
{
    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject('Hello Email')
        ->setFrom('test@yahoo.com')
        ->setTo('testswiftmailer@yopmail.com')
        ->setBody("test mail");
    //$mailer = $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
    $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
```

and thanks

Comment: Does the action work when commenting out the send()? When using the spool it will not send emails when there was some other error later on in the request, see: https://symfony.com/doc/current/email/spool.html#spool-using-memory "This means the email only gets sent if the whole request got executed without any unhandled exception or any errors."

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine at the first glance.

Maybe you could try setting the auth_mode to login

```
swiftmailer:
    auth_mode: login
```

also you could give tls instead of ssl encryption a try (in this case you should also set the port to 587 with `mailer_port: 587`).

Comment: thanks for your reply! when i change the encryptation and the port this exception appear Expected response code 220 but got code "421", with message "421 Cannot connect to SMTP server 87.248.118.22 (87.248.118.22:587), connect error 10060 "
end if i remove auth_mode: login when i have tls and 587 as parameters i have this Connection could not be established with host smtp.mail.yahoo.com [php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: H�te inconnu. #0]

Comment: this sounds a little like a network issues instead of a configuration issue. to confirm this you could test with another email provider like gmail. if the same problems occur it is most likely a network problem i think. are you in some kind of company network? otherwise your config seems fine

Comment: i tested all your proposition without any solution :'(